# Where is the "man from a foreign land" in Hyrule Town?

Tags: zelda-the-minish-cap

So I'm currently playing through the Legend of Zelda: Minish Cap for the first time. I have currently beaten the first dungeon and I have collected the earth element.

I went exploring Hyrule Town and while there, I found a man in a house claiming that he is "from a foreign land". His house also contains a "shrinking jar".

After searching his house for another ten minutes later that session, I can't seem to find his house again.

Is it currently unavailable at this point in the story or did I overlook something?

If possible, please mark his house on the map as I'm notoriously bad at following instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really sorry to everybody who helped and took the time to write an answer. My memory tricked me; The house containing the shrinking jar I was referencing was actually in the shoemaker's house on the main square:

[image: no]

Comment: Well, at least you found it again.

Answer (score 0):

If that "shrinking jar" is the only one present in Hyrule Town, according to [Zelda Dungeon wikia](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/wiki/Hyrule_Town):

> There is a Piece of Heart behind the motel that is accessible only in Link's Minish form. Link **must shrink to Minish size in the house at the southeast of Hyrule Town**, climb the small vine to the northeast and walk around behind the motel.

After whatching some Minish Cap videos, that shrinking jar is located in this house:
[image]

There's also a dog there.

Comment: There are about 4 houses which fit the description southeast.

Comment: @gurkensaas made an edit, is that guy?

Comment: I don't know and I currently have no means of trying, I will test it asap which means about 20 hours.

Comment: No rush, let me know

Comment: In this house, there is a jar, but not a jar which you can shrink with, at least not to my knowledge.

Comment: @gurkensaas for what I saw in [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/Fv0N_hbYRjI?t=30), Link does shrink after using that jar

Comment: Yes, you shrink after it being hit by the "rod". You don't have said rod at the current story progression.

Comment: @gurkensaas never played this game, my answer was just a speculation of what I've found :/

Answer (score 0):

From what I can recall, that's really not what @pinckerman is mentionning. The house with a dog and the neighboor house with a cat belongs to a couple. There's a shrinking jar in one of them you can flip with an item you maybe didn't already loot.

The house with the "foreign man" is here :

[image]

I'm not sure it contains a shrinking jar, thought. There's another way to access to the south-west part of the town that the dog is blocking.

Comment: This is the postman's house. It contains neither jar nor man from a foreign land.

Comment: I remember the postman's house is just the one above. Sorry for the mistake